# Is it possible to assign a new object into 'this'?

Tags: java, this

I have some calculation made in the constructor of a class
and now let assume I want to change one of the variable field in this class, which will affect the calculation that have been made before.

For each time I will call any `set` method
I will need to run again the calculation
(or copy the code twice (which is bad coding..))

I think the code will look better if I could do like as shown below,
I just want to know what is the reason it can't be done?

```
class Entity
{
    private int x,y,z;
    public Entity(int x,int y,int z)
    {
      Calculating();
    }
    private void Calculating()
    {
      // ... 
    }
    public void Set_X(int x)
    {
      this = new Entity(x,this.y,this.z)
    }
}
```

Comment: have you tried? Keep in mind that Java is case sensitive: Class Entity { } won't compile

Comment: I'm not seeing you do anything with the constructor arguments. Can yoi show us where they are being used please?

Comment: You can't assign to `this`.

Comment: @BenjaminUrquhart why would that matter?

Comment: I'm trying to compose an answer. Are you just assigning the arguments to your private instance ones?

Comment: @BenjaminUrquhart the instance members are not relevant to the question at hand. It's the instance he's asking about, not the instance members

Comment: I beg to differ. I want to know if setting the instance variable to the new X and calling Calculate again will update his value. Currently there's no way to tell.

Comment: @BenjaminUrquhart neither is there need to tell. it 'll fail whether there are instance variables or not.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot assign a new object to `this`. This always references the current object.

Why don't you just set X and invoke the `Calculting()` method from `Set_X`? This will change the current object's state.

If you do not want to change the current object, e.g. because of other references to it, you will have to create a new instance and return it from `Set_X`.